# How do you decrypt an encrypted SQLite database into memory and access it?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

We have an encrypted SQLite database provided with our app, and we want to decrypt the file into memory so that we can access the database.  How do we go about decrypting and accessing this database?

Comment: Do you mean you want the original file replaced by an unencrypted copy? If not, I am struggling to see how a file is significantly different from the sum of its contents.

Comment: How is the file encrypted? How is the reading not working? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Is this .sqlite file actually a text file with a different extension?  Have you opened it in a text editor like TextMate?

Comment: From the question I would assume that it isn't encrypted, he just doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments my friends.

@Jonathan - Yes i want my original file replaced by the decrypted copy, and the decryption is in runtime.

@Marcelo Cantos - Yes i need to be more specific, I have a encrypted <dbname>.sqlite file, which has to be decrypted during runtime. The decrypted file will be deleted when the app terminates leaving the encrypted ones in the app document space.

@slf - No i havent tried opening it in any other editors, it is a sqlite DB file. This DB file will contain the database tables and contents.

Comment: @Paul Lynch-Good one:),i really know what i have to do with it, believe me.

Comment: You need to be a lot more clear than just saying "it isn't working", then.

Comment: It depends on what exactly the project is. I cahved on this and it might help. very good resource here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571620/encrypt-decrypt-sqlite-database-and-use-it-ont-the-fly

Answer (score 0):

It's a database, and the api is provided on iPhone.  See http://www.sqlite.org/ for full details.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have already implemented all the DB and its complete routines, i am just stuck up with decrypting the file in runtime.